# Identityserver not returning User after successful signin redirect

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I am using following configuration in identityserver4 using oidc-client.js. It successfully does signin redirect. But "authUser" in following always comes null even after that. What's wrong am I doing. I followed their sample application.

```
const config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003",
};
const mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

mgr.getUser().then(function (authUser) {

    if (authUser) {
          //Home Page Coding will go here.
    }
    else {
        mgr.signinRedirect();
    }

});
```

Comment: please check your redirect_uri, this is where client gets token and other information from server to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually. I had not called following function. It was required.

```
signinRedirectCallback()
```